# Windows PHP scheduled task to restart service does not work

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

PHP version 5.2.2.6
OS: Windows Server 2003

I am trying to write a PHP script that will periodically check several windows services and restart any that are not running.

1) When I run from the web, the script works correctly.

2) When I run as scheduled tasks, the script runs but is unable to start any services.
I tried to output to a log text file. I see that it reports all services as stopped (even though some aren't), issues a service start for each but nothing happens. When I run the script from DOS prompt, same result.

I've tried various ways to start service and I get the same result.
EX:

```
system('net start ApDSCService');
```

I also tried this example but same results: http://hotware.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/restarting-windows-services-in-a-php-script/

I don't have the option to upgrade the PHP version as it would break some other sites hosted on the server.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the user in scheduled task (administrator if you can)

Comment: You're welcome. As your problem is solved, don't forget to click on the little tick on the left of my answer to accept my answer.